# UFW is Manually Disabled via Shell - Can the system re-enable it on boot?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

Take note i am already aware how to have start the ufw service on boot.  This is not what i am asking.

So, right now, if i check ufw status it shows as "Active".  And when i reboot and check status it still shows as "Active".  So al fine there.

What i am referring to is: if i type: **ufw disable** in shell it unloads the firewall and removes from startup.  Now, when i reboot the system, my ufw service will still run just fine but when i do a ufw status it shows the firewall is still not enabled.  To enable it i would have to type **ufw enable** in shell again.

Is there a way so even if i type ufw disable in shell that when i reboot the system will just make sure ufw enable happens so when i type ufw status each boot it shows it as "Active"?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: The manual says `reset`. I have not tried it.